# Closing External App with keyboard while not being at the form

Tags: c#

For a project, I want to show different pictures and videos. I have managed to change the pictures. But  I still have problems with showing different videos. I tried programming a process which opens VLC-Player. But this process does not close if I press the key which should kill the process

Is there any better solution?
My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Resources;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace keyboardNew
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Process ExternalProcess;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.A)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.nase3;
            }
            else if (e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.S)
            { 
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.nasefinal;
            }
            else if (e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.D) {

                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.seite_a;
                ExternalProcess.Kill();    
            }
            else if (e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.Z)
            {
                ExternalProcess = Process.Start("/filename.mp4");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's "the key which should kill the process"? Where is that piece of code?

Comment: @Alejandro "else if (e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.D) {

                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.seite_a;
                ExternalProcess.Kill();"

Comment: Code looks correct to me (although I won't use `Kill` to terminate a process), but I think that the code doesn't even fires because key events only ever go to the focused window and nothing else. I guess the media player has the focus in that moment.

Comment: You expect users to focus back on your app and hit `D` just to close down the player, rather than using, say, the close button or `ALT-F4` which are the standard ways of closing windows which will be ingrained behaviour for them?

Comment: Yes, it's only a part of a project. Actually, the user doesn't interact with the form directly. I have an Arduino which gives out key presses if an object with an RFID Tag is put on its scanner. So the idea is to show information about the object put on the scanner.

Comment: @Alejandro So is there a option for making the focus on the Form without hiding the video?

Comment: Using a keyboard shim should usually be an option of last resort - is there really no way to get a better *dedicated* communication channel between the scanner and this program (e.g. a dedicated interface pretending to be a serial port)?

Comment: Well, I am a pupil. This is my first project. That's the solution which my teacher gave me xD. I have not tried anything else, yet.

Comment: I'd suggest talking to your tutor then. If you're going the keyboard shim route, you have to be sure where the focus will be when it sends characters, which is difficult to control when launching separate processes. Might they have been expecting the use of a *component* that could be hosted within the application rather than an external exe/process?

Comment: There is the option to add another form with a video add on. But I think that is a very complicated way because I think it isn't possible to change the video in one Form. So I need a Form for every video which needs to played. The solution of my tutor was making different HTML pages and adding a code. But integrating full size videos in HTML isn't possible. So that's why I tried this solution.